# System.InvalidOperationException : Migration failed

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My solution have 3 projects :

1. Web (i added the connection string in the appsetting file)
2. Business (contains models class)
3. Infrastructure (contains DbContext)

I tried to make a migration :

```
dnx ef migration add firstMigration -s Web
```

I had this error :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'Infrastructure'.
Current runtime target framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1 (dnx451)'
Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16202
Type:         Clr
Architecture: x86
OS Name:      Windows
OS Version:   10.0
Runtime Id:   win10-x86
Please make sure the runtime matches a framework specified in project.json
```

When i put dnvm list, i have 1.0.0-rc1-final like a default runtime and i don't find 1.0.0*rc1-16202 in the list ?

The projet.json file of Infrastuture project is :

```
"frameworks": {
"dotnet5.4": {     
},
"net451": {
  "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  "frameworkAssemblies": { "System.Runtime": "4.0.10.0" }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by changing "net451" to "dnx451" in the project.json file under the "frameworks" object.

Comment: I tried it and i added (ef under the "commands" object). Now I have this error : Unable to load execute command 'EntityFramework.Commands'

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now, it was my mistake : i executed the command (dnx ef migrations add) in Infrasturtucre folder instead of web folder.